# Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Can't Find the Stopwatch class

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010 can't find the stopwatch class in any assembly.

Whenever I declare it in my code, VS gives an error saying that the type Stopwatch is not found.  I checked that I am referencing the correct assembly (system) and that I am using the full .NET framework 4.0.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Post a code snippet.  Make sure it contains `using System.Diagnostics`.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem when I developed a game based on Box2d.I sovled it by adding the "Microsoft.Phone" reference.I hope this method can help you or those who met this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when something like that happens it's because you have installed some beta version of a library (or a new beta version of .NET Framework). Anyway which language are you using?

(I assume you checked System.dll is referenced and you're not targeting/referencing the CF)

Answer (score 0):

Should be in System.dll, no?  I would verify that your references are including System.dll (ah, you say you have), and then try and explicitly reference it in your code as System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch and see if it resolves.

I would also verify the path to your referenced System.dll and ensure you're picking up the right one, and perhaps use ILSpy or Reflector to dig into the DLL and ensure it's there.